# KeyError: 'the label [2008-01-01] is not in the [index]'

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

I have a problem with my python code. I need to have the date of a certain year and it's weekdays in a dataframe and then hand it over to excel. It all seems to work fine, but I cannot address my index with the .loc command even though it is shown as an index, dtype: object. I always get the message KeyError:

```
'the label [2008-01-01] is not in the [index]'
```

As soon as I hand it over to excel my dates are converted to just ####, but the information is still a date, so I can easily convert them in excel to a date-format. Can anyone tell me how to fix those two problems? Thank you very very much!

This is my code:

```
Start_of_year = date(Year_Start, 01, 01)
End_of_year = date(Year_Start, 12, 31) 

Day_Difference = (End_of_year - Start_of_year).days 
Calender_List = []

for i in range(0, Day_Difference + 1):
   Date = Start_of_year + timedelta(i)
   Calender_List.append({'Datum': Date, 'Wochentag':  weekday[Date.weekday()]})

Calender = pd.DataFrame(Calender_List)
Calender.set_index('Datum', inplace=True)

print Calender.head() 

Calender.to_excel(writer, 'Jahr %s' % Year_Start)   
writer.save() 

print Calender.index 
print Calender.loc['2008-01-01']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having with selecting the index comes from the fact that you are searching for a string instead of a date object.
Instead, use the following:

```
print Calender.loc[date(2018, 01, 01)]
```

I don't quite understand your second issue, but to transfer to excel I would advise using pandas xlsxwriter. If the problem comes from the cell being too small, use:

```
worksheet.set_column(column, width)
```

If the problem is that your date isn't being recognized as a date, then format the cells or the column containing the dates

```
date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'yyyy/mm/dd'})
worksheet.write('A1', date, date_format)
-- or --
worksheet.set_column(column, width, format)
```

Comment: Thank you very very much! It solved all my problems!! :-) i had the second issue with the date, and now it works just perfectly fine :-) Thank you again for your quick support :-)